# Isotope filter doesn't fire callback on 'layout'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using isotope filters in combination with bootstrap tabs to switch between two isotope filters in their own tab content divs.

Because tabs hide/show the tab content I have to call the isotope `layout` command each time a tab is active. I'd like to control adding a css class to the isotope container *after* the layout command to the isotope is done.

But, when I call jQuery's `addClass()` from an anonymous callback to the isotope instance it never fires:

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ( $($(this).attr('href') + '[class*=isotope-container]') ) {
            $($(this).attr('href')).isotope('layout', function() {
                $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('trans-height');
                console.log("My callback fired");
            });
    }
}
```

I never see the console log nor does `trans-height` get added to the isotope-container

I made sure that my isotope container div includes a class with the substring `isotope-container` and that the call to the isotope `layout` works: if I remove this code then my isotope just clumps up when the tab is shown, but nicely spreads out when it is included.

I realize I can just add the class using a relatively safe `setTimeout()` but I'd like to understand why the callback is not firing. It seems that's the correct way to do things.

Any idea why the callback is not firing?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I really thought Boris' suggestion would work but when I did this I saw the first alert for `shown.bs.tab` but the second alert never happens:

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
            if ( $($(this).attr('href') + '[class*=isotope-container]') ) {

                $isotopeContainer = $($(this).attr('href'));
                $isotopeContainer.on('layoutComplete', function() {
                    alert("Layout is complete");
                    $(this).addClass('trans-height');
                });

                alert("Tab containing isotope has been shown");
                $($(this).attr('href')).isotope('layout');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you talking about [this isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it looks like [layout method](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html) doesn't expect any parameter.

But there is an [layoutComplete event](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html), so you can try this:

```
$('isotope-selector').on('layoutComplete', function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('trans-height');
    console.log("My callback fired");
});
$('isotope-selector').isotope('layout');
```

Comment: @river_jones try to use `$isotopeContainer.one('layoutComplete'...`, `one` instead of `on`, maybe multiple callbacks somehow break it. Also it would be great if you setup the demo plunker or jsfiddle, so it will be easier to check.